# Internal IP of Azure website connect to VNet via VPN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, vpn, azure-virtual-network

I have an azure website connect to my azure VNET via point to site connection. Its working well and I'm able to access VM's on the network from the site. However, is there a way for the VM's to access the site via the network using internal IP? I've been unable to find out what the internal IP of the my azure website is.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to host your web app in an App Service Environment (ASE) to get a dedicated internal IP address for your web app instance(s).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-configure-an-app-service-environment/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be able to obtain VIP for your website is to host it as a cloud service which provision a VM and therefore you can connect to your VNET.

And the way to do this is just add a cloud service to your solution and then app your website as a web role! and publish.

Hope this helps.